# PhpMyAdmin - how to increase the number of columns visible in the browse menu

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database in the PhpMyAdmin platform and i'm checking the data that i have inside a table, in the "browse" menu, but for some reason there is one column that doesn't displays a name.

For example, in the structure menu i can see all the names of the columns, and in this case the name is "X", but when i go to browse menu, for some reason the name of that field displays empty. I don't know if it may help but that column is the 14th, and the 15th and the columns after that have the same problem.

Comment: If a column is empty then it will not be visible under the browse tab.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says:

> Show: 30 row(s) starting from row # 0  in Horizantal mode and repeat
>   headers after 100  cells

Try setting the mode to vertical, or to rotated headers